# MySQL case when count distinct inside where

Tags: mysql, count, case, distinct, where-clause

Im trying to do below code but having error

```
WHERE (case when (Count(distinct idc) >= 2) then idw NOT LIKE '%_pronto_' ELSE TRUE end)
```

sometimes I have dupe 'idc' values, if so I want to exclude lines where column idw  have string like '%*pronto*'

Those are results from a query, and I need to filter it in an outer query:

```
# userid, idw,        uniq, idc
193,   q3470_pronto_, 0,   3470
193,   q3470_next_,   1,   3470
193,   q3496_alt_1_,  10,  34961
193,   q3498_alt_3_,  11,  34983
193,   q3499_alt_2_,  12,  34992
```

in this case above I want to exclude row 1 because I have more than 1 idc = 3470
and row 1 have idw like %*pronto*

I need it because sometimes I have a uniq idc and I need to keep *pronto*

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Comment: You can't use aggregate functions like `COUNT()` in the WHERE clause. Try HAVING instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can work for you:

```
select *
from t
where find_in_set(uniq, (
            select group_concat(uniqs)
            from (
                select group_concat(case when t2.idw like '%\_pronto\_' then t2.uniq end) as uniqs
                from t t2
                group by userid,
                    idc
                having count(*) > 1
                ) t
            )) = 0;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/CDHFD3600)

Comment: actually I can't select table 't', because my values are generated by a sub query. So I have a query that return this values and I want to filter it in an  outer query

Comment: @Flib - you can put your query in the above two places (before t) and it should work.

Comment: I think it worked! But My query is too big. Not sure if tis good to have it two times. any idea ?

Comment: @flib I cant comment without the actual query